# change text-align to left with javascript for all classes with text-align justify

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, uiwebview

There is some static HTML content which I need to display on a mobile device. These files already have their CSS styles, with many many classes.

To improve readability on a small screen I want to change all classes with text-align:justify to text-align:left.

I think the most appropriate solution would be to modify the styles in `webViewDidFinishLoad` method. How can I accomplish this using Javascript?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this:

```
var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
for( i=0; i < styleSheets.length; i++ ){
    for( j=0; j < styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; j++){
        var rule = styleSheets[i].cssRules[j];            
        if(rule.style.textAlign=='justify'){
            rule.style.textAlign='left';
        }
    }
}
```

This works but I am still interested in more elegant solutions w/o jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a horrible way that i wouldn't actually use myself as it adds an inline style to every element. I can't think of any other way of doing it without specifying the classes or elements you want it to act on.

http://jsfiddle.net/alangilby/e7XfU/

Interesting experiment though. oh and you don't want jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but, thought I'd provide my answer for reference. Not sure if this will help for what you needed, but, here is one, non-jQuery way I've used in the past to apply text-align:left to the entire body..

```
    NSString* css = @"\"body { text-align:left;}\"";
    NSString* js = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                    @"var styleNode = document.createElement('style');\n"
                    "styleNode.type = \"text/css\";\n"
                    "var styleText = document.createTextNode(%@);\n"
                    "styleNode.appendChild(styleText);\n"
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleNode);\n",css];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```